# Renumber bibliography in references

Tags: biblatex, numbering

I am looking to get a continuation of numbers in my bibliography under my articles section, but as I have included a `@misc` to include hyperlinks in the articles section this is what I get:

[image]

```
    \documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry} \usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{calc}
%\usepackage[refsection=chapter,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[refsection=chapter,defernumbers=true,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}
\addbibresource{5.bib}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\newcommand*{\refname}{Bibliography}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{book1,
    address = {New York},
    publisher = {John Wiley \& Sons},
    author = {Egan, Willian F.},
    title = {Phase-Lock Basics},
    year = {1998},
    %volume = {3},
    %series = {2},
    edition = {1},
    pages = {3--4},
    %month = {January}
}

@article{art1,
    address = {City},
    publisher = {Myself},
    author = {Doe, John},
    title = {Synthesizer Modulation},
    year = {1979},
    %volume = {14},
    %number = {6},
    %pages = {1--8},
    month = {June}
}

@book{book2,
    address = {New York},
    publisher = {John Wiley \& Sons},
    author = {Gardner, Floyd M.},
    title = {Phaselock Techniques},
    year = {2005},
    %volume = {14},
    %number = {6},
    pages = {6--28},
    %month = {June}
}

@book{book3,
    address = {California},
    publisher = {Benjamin/Cummings},
    author = {Norman S.},
    title = {Control Systems Engineering},
    year = {1995},
    %volume = {3},
    %series = {2},
    edition = {2},
    pages = {231--232},
    %month = {February}
}

@article{art2,
    address = {Plantation},
    publisher = {Myself},
    author = {Me.},
    title = {Lock Time Performance},
    year = {1990},
    %volume = {14},
    %number = {6},
    %pages = {1--8},
    month = {June}
}

@misc{pll_wikipedia,
    howpublished = {\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked loop}},
    author = {Wikipedia},
    %note = {Last visited on <insert date here>},
    title = {Phase-Locked Loop},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
Some  text \autocite{book1,art1}.


\section{Second}

Some  text \autocite{book2}.

Some  text \autocite{book1}.

Some  text \autocite{art2}.

Some  text \autocite{art1}.

Some  text \autocite{pll_wikipedia}.

\chapter*{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{ocre}{Bibliography}}
\section*{Books}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Books}
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=book,prefixnumbers={B}]
\section*{Articles}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Articles}
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=article,prefixnumbers={A}]
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=misc,prefixnumbers={A}]
\chapter{Chapter 2}
Some  text \autocite{book2}
\chapter*{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{ocre}{Bibliography}}
\section*{Books}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Books}
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=book,prefixnumbers={B}]
\section*{Articles}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Articles}
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=article,prefixnumbers={A}]
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=misc,prefixnumbers={A}]
\end{document}
```

I wanted the Articles numbering to continue within the chapter although I have a hyperlink reference.

Comment: Each `\printbibliography` uses an own counter.  If you use this macro two times with the same prefixnumbers A for both you get two two A1.

To avoid this add a section "Online" with a new prefixnumber, for example `O`.

If you want to have separate bibliographys for each chapter the prefixnumbers have to to not identical (remember please: each \printbibliography` has an own counter!). Use for example `A1-` etc.

Comment: You can issue a `\printbibliography[nottype=book]` in order to print everything else without reseting the counter (if you only have article and misc-entries).

Comment: @Joe Did you find what you were looking for in my answer?

Comment: @karlkoeller I did get my original question solved by you.  THANKS! As per your suggestion, I started up this other thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have some different choices. Please note that I've changed `Wikipedia` to `ikipedia` just to show how the sorting mechanism works.

1. If you want a separate bibliography for `@misc` entries, you can  add something like

   ```
   \section*{Online}
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Online}
   \printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=misc,prefixnumbers={O}]
   ```

   The result will be:

   [image]
2. If you don't want a separate bibliography for `@misc` entries, and you only have `@misc` and `@article` entries apart from `@book`, you can use the option `nottype=book` as suggested by henrique

   ```
   \printbibliography[heading=bibempty,nottype=book,prefixnumbers={A}]
   ```

   The result will be:

   [image]

   As you can see `@misc` and `@article` entries are mixed.
3. If you don't like the previous behavior (mixed `@misc` and `@article` entries), and you want all `@misc` entries to be listed after `@article` entries, you can adopt this trick: add the field `presort = {zz}` to all `@misc` entries, e.g.

   ```
   @misc{pll_wikipedia,
       howpublished = {\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked loop}},
       author = {ikipedia},
       %note = {Last visited on <insert date here>},
       title = {Phase-Locked Loop},
       presort = {zz}
   }
   ```

   The field `presort` is the first used for sorting and, if not specified, it has the value `mm`.

   The result will be:

   [image]
4. If you have entry types different from `@misc` and `@article`, and you want a bibliography that lists only `@misc` and `@article` entries, you can follow this way: add a new "filter" in the preamble:

   ```
   \defbibfilter{extarticle}{%
   type=article 
   or type=misc
   }
   ```

   and then substitute the line

   ```
   \printbibliography[heading=bibempty,nottype=book,prefixnumbers={A}]
   ```

   with

   ```
   \printbibliography[heading=bibempty,filter=extarticle,prefixnumbers={A}]
   ```

---

### Warning

If you don't get the above results after compiling, you have to delete all auxiliary files before recompiling (at least the `.aux` and `.bbl`).