# Custom sorting in biblatex taking type into account

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I am using `biblatex` for the first time, and was looking at the customisation section in the manual, but couldn't find what I was looking for. I want to define a sort order such that all books come first, then all articles and finally all remaining types of entries. Can this be done using the available commands or should I add custom fields to my BibTeX file?

Comment: Probably you might want something like the one described in this thread: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131962/27635

Comment: Indeed, it was the option defernumbers=true that I was looking for, since I split my bibliography according to type. I was looking in the sorting section, but the solution clearly was in a completely different part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I split my bibliography according to entry type, the solution lies not in the sorting, but in the package option `defernumbers`. If this option is set to `true`, then the numbers are only assigned when the bibliography is printed, and thus all books are numbered first, then articles and finally the remaining resources.